# httpd error log : [client 127.0.0.1] Attempt to serve directory: /var/www/html/

Tags: log-files

I was looking through my server's error logs, because it has been crashing lately, and I noticed this error occuring constantly:

> [Mon Feb 04 17:26:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Attempt to serve
>   directory: /var/www/html/
>
> [Mon Feb 04 17:26:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/html/io
>
> [Mon Feb 04 17:26:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/html/io
>
> [Mon Feb 04 17:26:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/html/pinger
>
> [Mon Feb 04 17:26:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/html/pinger
>   mysqldump: Got error: 2005: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (1) when trying to connect

I hosted my wordpress website under /var/www/vhosts//httpdocs/ path and there is no issue with load the site and the performance of the website. But how to rid of this error as some time the site hangs and after httpd restart site came live again. Does this error causes my site to go down

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something or someone on your server is trying to do a curl or wget on localhost (this is a pretty common thing for nagios to do if you're using nrpe for example.)  If you comment out that section of httpd.conf, apache will stop looking there for files to serve (which, of course, may break whatever is running on the host that is doing the web request for localhost.)

Comment: I guess the Wordpress ping update services is causing the trouble which is in the writing section. Removed it and updated from [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Update_Services). Let me observe for quite some time.